# S3 Prefix event trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following bucket structure

```
Mybucket
    -user1
        -application_log
        -stack_log
        -memory_log
    -user2
        -application_log
        -stack_log
        -memory_log
    -user3
        -application_log
        -stack_log
        -memory_log
```

I want to trigger the S3 events only when data is uploaded under **application_log** sub-folder.
I tried to use wild card under `Prefix` for `Event Notification` like `*/application_log/` but after going through the docs I came to know that wildcards are not treated like wildcards.
How can I achieve this, because in future I will be having more folders like `user4,user5....usern` at root, but I want to trigger only when data is uploaded to `application_log`

Comment: Can't you get the info (bucket name) from the S3 Event Notification info passed to Lambda? Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: What you want is simply not supported by S3 events. You have to re-architect your bucket structure and start with `/application_log/user1`, `/application_log/user2` and so on.

Comment: The problem I have here is in one of the other folder `stack_log` I literally have 1000-2000 files uploaded,  , so if I keep Event trigger for everything then those many lambda's will be triggered